# How to disable 'Beep' sound when maxLength is reached in Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for my poor English.

I wanna disable 'Beep' sound in textbox.

I tried like below.

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == ((TextBox)sender).MaxLength)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.TextBox_KeyPress);
```

It works, but editing text is also disabled after maxlength is reached.

I still wanna edit text in textbox even if the maximum length is reached.

I don't need 'Beep' sound in my application, so it is okay to disable 'Beep' sound in whole application.

How can I disable it?

Comment: *"I don't need 'Beep' sound in whole application"* - this beep is one of system alerts and it's not for you, it's for all users. It tells user about error. It's good to have. Why do you want to disable it? What problem it causes specifically?

Comment: You just need to exclude keychars such as backspace, ctrl+V and ctrl+X. (delete is handled differently I think)

Comment: @Bizhan OMG It's so simple! Why I didn't think of it?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome, you also need to check for selection (user can select part of text and type to replace that selected part)